# How to patch google.cloud.storage in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-mock

I have a class that import google cloud:

StorageUtils:

```
from google.cloud import storage
```

I have a app that uses StorageUtils:

App:

```
import StorageUtils
```

Then I have a test, that I want to test my app

Test:

```
from app import App
```

I want to test my app without using google cloud. The easiest way I found is to use sys.modules:

```
import sys
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
sys.modules["google.cloud.storage"] = MagicMock()
```

I found this solution quite a work around. Are there any other way using python mock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, if the file that contains the class StorageUtils is called storage_utils.py:

```
#test_storage.py
@patch("storage_utils.storage")
def test_storage(st):
    storage = StorageUtils()
```